# How do I declare an option that takes an input value?

Tags: packages, package-writing

I know I can declare and execute an option for my package using

```
\DeclareOption{myoption}{\typeout{I did it!}}
\ProcessOptions
```

but now I'd like to give the option a value:

```
\DeclareOption{type}{\typeout{You typed: \CurrentOptionValue}}
```

which would be used as follows:

```
\usepackage[type="hello, world!"]{mypackage}
```

Requirements on the value string is that it can contain at least some nonalphanumeric characters, like spaces, commas and dots (and maybe some others...).

Comment: Do you mean just any option or specifically a key-value one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For handling key-value input as package options, there are a few choices:

1. [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval)
2. [`kvoptions`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions)
3. [`pgfopts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts)

Of these, `kvoptions` is probably the most robust approach. The way that options are declared is to use `\define@key` (or `\pgfkeys` in the case of `pgfopts`) before processing the package options. With `kvoptions` you get some nicer wrappers, such as `\DeclareBoolOption`.

However, the LaTeX2e kernel does various bits of processing before the input gets anywhere near the key-value processor. As a result, I'd strongly advice considering using a post-loading macro to set keys rather than a load-time set of options. This is easy enough to implement:

```
\def\mysetupmacro#1{\setkeys{mypackage}{#1}}
```

which will then only need a basic key-value package: probably I would choose [`kvsetkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kvsetkeys), which provides `\kvsetkeys` as a more robust version of `\setkeys`.

Comment: Forgot about `pgfopts` and didn't know about `kvoptions`.  Thanks for those.

Comment: "However, the LaTeX2e kernel does various bits of processing before..." In particular, the kernel gobbles punctuation, causing arguments like `type="hello, world!"` to fail. Not all is lost. Should you really need to pass spaces via package options, you can escape them like this: `type="hello,\ world!"` However, other punctuation can't be escaped  (your `!` will lead to trouble). Joseph is spot-on about this. PS, `xkeyval` more or less supersets `kvoptions`, is feature-rich, and is certainly equally robust. `pgfopts` exposes `pgfkeys` for package writers (for which, see the PGF\TikZ manual).

Answer (score 1):

The [xkeyval](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=xkeyval) package is your friend.